# How to change OpenStreetMap Layer Properties in QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, plugins, toolbar

I have loaded the OpenStreetMap layer in QGIS 2.0, but would like to edit the properties in order to better complement the map I'm producing. I can't seem to find the OSM toolbar or OSM Feature widget that allows me to edit. Is this  because OSM has been integrated into the core functionality of QGIS 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

The old Openstreetmap plugin had the ability to edit and upload the data back to the OSM Servers. This was dropped, because the OSM editors are better, and keeping up to date with the OSM tagging would need more time than the plugin authors want to spend on it.

You can however change properties of the points, lines and polygons layers inside QGIS, as you do with every other layer.

---

**EDIT**

The content of http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/osm/openstreetmap.html is outdated. It still describes the old OSM plugin which was cancelled with QGIS 2.0.

Comment: How do I change the properties of the points, lines and polygons as you mentioned? I can't seem to find the tools that do this.

Comment: Switch the layer to edit mode, select the item you want to change, open the attribute table, change the attribute you want to be different, save and leave edit mode. That's basic editing in QGIS. Or do you ask about styling?

Comment: It appears I am asking about styling and not editing the data of the layer. I would like to be able to select which features of OSM are displayed.

Comment: You can find some sample OSM styles at https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/styles

Comment: @Andre Joost - Can the OpenStreet layer be edited? I cannot find any way to do that. I, too, would like to use the layer but don't want any commercial enterprises on my layer. I can't see how to delete them through QGIS 2.2

Comment: You can save the point/line/polygon layers to spatialite and work with that just as every other data source. But don't mix up this OSM layer with the one coming from the Openlayers plugin, which can not be edited.